# Set alias for index using PHP client library in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch

I am creating search application using elasticsearch. I want to make indexing with zero downtime. I found one solution using aliases with client library in php. But I don't know how to implement it using client library in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to add an alias to an existing index, you need to call the `updateAliases` method:

```
$params['body'] = array(
    'actions' => array(
        array(
            'add' => array(
                'index' => 'your_index',
                'alias' => 'your_alias'
            )
        )
    )
);
$client->indices()->updateAliases($params);
```

Comment: How will I get index name from alias in elasticsearch using client library.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a more complete solution, have a look at http://elasticorn.net - you can configure your index via yaml and it automatically creates them with aliases and the possibility to remap / reconfigure indices on the fly.